# How to open a submission target="_blank" in tab rather than popup for Chrome

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using the following code

```
<form id="export" target="_blank" action='exported_data.php' method="get" >
<input type="hidden" id="data" name="data" value="">
</form>
```

this is my JS

```
$.ajax({ url: baseUrl + 'entities/GetExportDetails/entity/'+entity,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        data: {"id": recordid},
        success: function( response ) {
        $("#data").val(response);
        $("#export").submit();
    }       
    });
```

Now the issue is that I am using the **target=_blank** in the form . When I submit the Form in FF or in IE the exported_data.php opens in a new tab but in Chrom it is opening in a pop-up. I don't want it to be opened in the Pop-Up. Can u please help me that It opens in the new tab in all browsers

Comment: It is an issue of the browser options on client side.

Comment: How can I check this issue??

Comment: It is not possible to check the slected values, especially in InternetExplorer

Comment: How do you trigger your ajax?

Comment: @reporter That sounds like it may be possible in other browsers. Is it?

Comment: @mplungjan There is a label before the Form. the Ajax is triggered on click of that label

Comment: Compare to IE, FF and Chrome uses textfiles to store thier options. This fact increases your chance to do something just a little bit (let's say from 0.0001% to ~0.001%). However, accept it that is not possible with resumable value of work.

Comment: @mplungjan No its not a duplicate .. Because I am having the Popups.. which I don't want at all

Comment: and that is not "new window doesn't open as tab" ???

Comment: I Don't think its same.. Just don't focus on title :)

Comment: @NabeelArshad It definitely is the same. *Can u please help me that It opens in the new tab in all browsers* - the linked question provides a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

The choice to open in a new tab or window cannot be configured by us. Its dependent on the browser settings. We can only provide an option to open in a new tab/window or replace the contents in the existing window.

Comment: Can u please give me any reference to your statement ???